# unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I'm consolidating the data from different workbook into a master workbook. But after consolidating I need to the remove the duplicate..
Work sheet

Work sheet
:---------------
Task Category   Task Description/ Detail    Assigned To     Assigned Date   Expected Delivery  Date Actual Completion Date  Status
:-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Analysis    Task1   Maaya   02-01-2017  19-01-2017  19-01-2017  Completed
Analysis    Task2   Maaya   02-01-2017  19-01-2017  19-01-2017  Completed
Analysis    Task3   Maaya   20-01-2017  10-03-2017  10-03-2017  Completed
Analysis    Task4   Maaya   20-01-2017  10-03-2017  10-03-2017  Completed
Coding & Testing    Task5   Maaya   01-03-2017  10-03-2017  10-03-2017  Completed
Coding & Testing    Task5   Maaya   01-03-2017  10-03-2017      Ongoing

With the code below I'm able to remove the duplicated... But the TASK5 having 2 status like Completed and Ongoing. I need the latest updated data.

Code is here:

```
Public Sub duplicate_removal()
Dim Colm, lastrow As String
Dim i, Value1, Value2 As Integer
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Work Management").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Work Management").Sort.SortFields.Add 
Key:=Range("F3:F104857"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Work Management").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A3:X104857")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
End With
Colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("ID", Sheets("Work Management").Rows(1), 0)
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, Colm).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow

   Value1 = Range("C" & i).Value
  Value2 = Range("C" & i + 1).Value


    If Value1 = Value2 Then
    Rows(i).Delete
    End If

MsgBox ("Duplicates removed ")

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the Code. You have a code line like this,

```
Colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("ID", Sheets("Work Management").Rows(1), 0)
```

It is looking for the Column Header - "ID" which you don't have in your data. If you change that your own column header which you need. It will work

Comment: ok I have changed as Task desc... but still getting error at Value2 = Range("N" & i + 1).Value as typo error 13

Comment: @Maaya That's a different error. Please post a new question along with your data as you have posted your code and not as an image. Kindly accept this answer as it answered your question :)

Comment: @Maaya Your question has been answered. Accept the answer and start a new question !